# Prevent Dell monitor from taking over audio output

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a Dell U2414H monitor which I use via HDMI with my Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS laptop. The monitor doesn't have builtin speakers, but I think it can forward sound via HDMI to Audio-Line out, to which you can connect some external speaker but I don't have any such speakers attached and I don't want to use this feature. However, the monitor always take over the sound output when I connect it to my laptop and I've to manually switch back to default audio output.

Is there any way I can make Ubuntu remember not to switch to this specific device when I connect it? To be clear I'm not asking to always lock to the laptop's builtin speakers instead I just want Ubuntu to not consider my monitor as an output device, this way I can continue to have seamless switch over when I connect any headphones.